# Открытие другого окна при запуске приложения Builder c++

Tags: c++

Как открыть другое окно при запуске приложения в builder c++?

Comment: что значит другое окно ? окно чужого приложения ? или форму не основную из своего ?

Comment: Ну есть окно, которое открывается автоматически. Но мне нужно, чтобы сначала открывалось второе окно. Типа хочу сделать главное меню, через которое вызывать другие окна

Comment: откройте главный файл проэкта там где WinMain и в WinMain поправьте.

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось. Много раз в коде лазил, а мимо глаз проходило!